# How to rename files into incremental sequential order using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple files:

```
12345678 (1).pdf
12345678 (2).pdf
12345678 (3).pdf  
12345678 (4).pdf
12345678 (5).pdf
```

The number `12345678` is variable. Currently, I have the code

```
cd C:\folder
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
    set f=%%a
    set f=!f:^(=!
    set f=!f:^)=!
    ren "%%a" "!f!"

    if /i "%~1"=="/R" (
        set "forOption=%~1 %2"
        set "inPath="
    ) else (
        set "forOption="

    if "%~1" neq "" (set "inPath=%~1\") else set "inPath="
    )

    for %forOption% %%F in ("%inPath%* *") do (
        if /i "%~f0" neq "%%~fF" (
            set "folder=%%~dpF"
            set "file=%%~nxF"
            setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
            echo ren "!folder!!file!" "!file: =!"
            ren "!folder!!file!" "!file: =!"
            endlocal
        )
    )
)
```

This changes the file name to the following

```
123456781.pdf
123456782.pdf
123456783.pdf
123456784.pdf
123456785.pdf
```

The outcome is to make files incrementing based  on the previous generated

```
12345678.pdf
12345679.pdf
12345680.pdf
12345681.pdf
12345682.pdf
```

Comment: What happened to 6 and 7?

Comment: The files continue                                                                                       12345678 (1).pdf
12345678 (2).pdf
12345678 (3).pdf  
12345678 (4).pdf
12345678 (5).pdf
12345678 (6).pdf..... I am looking to increment based on the previous number. the number 12345678 can be any number

Comment: take the last character of the filename (exlucing extenstion) and +1 in a loop.

Comment: Thank you. How do I do this? I am not very good with Batch files

Comment: will there ever be `12345678.pdf` at all?

Comment: Yes. if the first file name is 12345678 (1).pdf it will become 12345678.pdf. The next one should become 12345679.pdf. 12345678 can be any number in the beginning. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I had time for now:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.pdf) do (
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%%i") do (
     set num=%%b
     set num=!num:%%~xb=!
     set num=!num:^(=!
     set num=!num:^)=!
     set /a num=!num!-1
     set "minname=%%a"
     set lastchar=!minname:~-1!
     set newname=!minname:~0,-1!
     set /a cnt=+1
     set /a fin=!lastchar!+!num!
     echo ren "%%i" "!newname!!fin!%%~xi"
  )
 )
```

with my test results being:

```
ren "12345678 (1).pdf" "12345678.pdf"
ren "12345678 (2).pdf" "12345679.pdf"
ren "12345678 (3).pdf" "123456710.pdf"
....
```

So we first take all `pdf` files, if the file already exists called `12345678.pdf` we do nothing, then we split their name by whitespace, being the space after the actual numeric number, but before the opening parenthesis. then we just take the last char (being 8) and plus the number between the parenthesis, minus 1.

The output above only `echo`s the ren output, so remove `echo` to actually perform the ren task.

**EDIT**

After your requirement changes in the comments and question, which is now much easier to achieve, as we take the entire number plus the number in the parenthesis, and minus 1:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.pdf) do (
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%%i") do (
     set num=%%b
     set num=!num:%%~xb=!
     set num=!num:^(=!
     set num=!num:^)=!
     set /a num=!num!-1
     set "minname=%%a"
     set /a newname=minname+num
     echo ren "%%i" !newname!%%~xi
  )
 )
```

This will increment the entire number range growing the entire range, which makes more sense than the first solution you required.

Comment: Thank you Gerhard. It works perfectly if the file is 1234578.pdf . But the file name can be anything xxxxxx (1). xxxxxx (2). Thank you once again

Comment: But will the name always be numerical?

Comment: @priam I edited the code. It simply filtered on that number based on my tests. It will work for any numericaly named pdf file with the parenthesized values as per your examples.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gerhard Barnard. It works like a charm. Much gratitude

Comment: I have one problem, I just realised that if the output is for example xxx19, the next one is coming as xxx110. Is it possible to make to xxx20? Thank you once again Gerhard @GerhardBarnard

Comment: Sorry again @Gerhard. I have now edited the "outcome of the solution" in the question. I had made an error. My question was not clearly explicit.

Comment: @Priam See the edited code at the bottom regarding the requirement change.

Comment: Thank you once again. Much gratitude @Gerhard Barnard

Comment: No problem. Does it increment as intended?